# Word description of classes design task?

Tags: c++, oop, class

I have this question:

> Start with publication, book and tape classes. Add a base class sales
>   that holds an array of three floats so that it can record the dollar
>   sales of a particular publication for the last three months. Include a
>   getdata() function to get three sales amounts from the user and a
>   putdata() function to display the sales figures. Alter the book and
>   tape classes so they are derived from both publication and sales. An
>   object of class book or tape should input sales data along with its
>   other data. Write a main() program to create a book object and a tape
>   object and exercise their input/output capabilities.

I didn't understand it very well, in which class should I include getdata() & putdata() functions! I wrote this code till now:

```
   #include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class sales{
private:
    float dollar[3];
public:
    void getData(float f1,float f2, float f3){
        dollar[0]=f1;// sales of first month
        dollar[1]=f2;// sales of second month
        dollar[2]=f3;// sales of third month
    }
    void putData(){
        int count=0;
        while(count!=3){
        cout<<dollar[count]<<"\t$"<<endl;
        count++;
        }
    }
};


class publication:public sales{
private:
    string PubName;
    int PubYear;
public:
    void SetName(string s){
        PubName=s;
    }
    string GetName(){
        return PubName;
    }
        void SetYear(int y){
        PubYear=y;
    }
    int GetYear(){
        return PubYear;
    }
};

class book:public publication{
private:
    string Author;
public:
    void SetAuthor(string a){
        Author=a;
    }
    string GetAuthor(){
        return Author;
    }


};

class tape:public publication{
private:
    string singer;
public:
    void SetSinger(string s){
        singer=s;
    }
    string GetSinger(){
        return singer;
    }


};



int main() {
    tape Tobj;
    book Bobj;

// input/output capabilities of tape object.
    Tobj.getData(33,55,88);
    Tobj.SetName("General music tape");
    Tobj.SetSinger("David");
    Tobj.SetYear(2011);
    cout<<Tobj.GetName()<<" for "<<Tobj.GetSinger()<<"\nattained the following sales for the last three months:"<<endl;
    Tobj.putData();
    cout<<"in "<<Tobj.GetYear()<<endl<<endl<<endl;

// input/output capabilities of book object.    
    Bobj.getData(65.6,585,808.2);
    Bobj.SetName("Art of math");
    Bobj.SetAuthor("John");
    Bobj.SetYear(2009);
    cout<<Bobj.GetName()<<" for "<<Bobj.GetAuthor()<<"\nattained the following sales for the last three months:"<<endl;
    Bobj.putData();
    cout<<"in "<<Bobj.GetYear()<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

Is what I did true!

Comment: You honestly made a **screenshot of text** rather than type *your* question here? This must be a contender for the Lazy Ass badge!

Comment: as getdata() is a **function** may be it should not be included in any class?

Comment: @Stals: I don't think the term is used to mean non-method here. main() is called a program, not a function. Placement in class sales seems reasonable given the problem description (publication seems off, though).

Comment: @KerrekSB Take it easy. Downvote and move on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Include a getdata() function to get three sales amounts from the user and a putdata() function to display the sales figures."

With the way that it is worded, it suggests to me that getData() and putData() should be part of a "User" class.  But since there isn't a "User" class, it looks to me like you put it in the right place.